# Matlab: How to boxplot sparse data with coherent spacing on x axis

Tags: matlab

I have to boxplot some data with MATLAB.

And I have the labels:

```
x = [1 , 2 , 3 , 5 , 10 , 50 , 100 , 110 , 150 , 200 ]
```

And I have some data, say:

```
for j=1:10
for i=1:10
y(j,i) = x(i)*rand()
end
end
```

Now when I launch
    boxplot(y,x)
I obtain a fixed gap between x labels. For example 1 has the same distance from 2 as that of 150 to 200. How can I set this distance proportional to the actual gap?

Comment: what is the plot-command you are using?

Comment: how are you plotting? `plot(x,y)`? Also are x and y actual sparse matirces as in the sparse matrix data type?

Comment: Now I'm using boxplot, but I have the same problem when using plot(x,y)

Comment: @HAL9000 It woiuld help if you posted you plotting code and an image of the plot highlighting your issue

Comment: Sorry, I verified that with plot(x,y) it actually works. However my code looks like this:
boxplot(data,x)
where data is a matrix containing a vector for each x, while x is the vector x = [1 , 2 , 3 , 5 , 10 , 50 , 100 ]

Comment: @HAL9000 please *edit your question* to include a sample of `data` and also this `boxplot` code you just posted plus anything else we need to reproduce the issue on our side

Comment: I hope now is more clear, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming (from the comments) that you're using boxplot from the statistics toolbox:

In boxplot(data,x), x is assumed to be information on groups - e.g. this is not anything to do with positions along the x-axis but information on how to group the data. In this example using built in data:

```
load carsmall
boxplot(MPG,Model_Year)
```

Both MPG and Model_Year are 100 x 1 doubles - Model_Year contains 3 unique values (70, 76, 82), e.g. the number of groups in this data is 3.  The output is a plot with three boxes showing MPG for those three years - but the position, by default, of the boxes is 1:numGroups.

You can change this behaviour, but you need to use parameters:

```
data = randn(100,7);
x = [1 , 2 , 3 , 5 , 10 , 50 , 100];
boxplot(data,'position',x)
```

You might need to play with some of the other plotting parameters (box width, etc) to make it look nice.

Answer (score 0):

The smoothness of a curve depends upon the resolution of the data and upon the amount of zooming that one has done on the figure.

You have a parabolic equation like `y=x*x` (this is not exact, as that of yours)

So, you can try something like following:

```
>> x = [1:.025:100];
>> y=x.*x;
>> plot(x,y)
```